# IIS with SQLLocalDB return null on queries with error in Windows Event viewer error 528

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis

I am developing an ASP.NET website with a SQL Server 2019 LocalDB database. I was working in Windows 10 ver:1903, but after upgrading Windows to the latest version, the website still starts, but has no connectivity to SQL Server `(LocalDB)`.

There is a .NET exception when connecting to SQL Server, at the same time, multiple of this error will be logged in the Windows event viewer:

> Source:        SQLLocalDB 15.0
> Event ID:      528
> Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error code: 575. Windows system error message is: {Application Error}
> The application was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.
> Reported at line: 3714.

This special webSite is running on Windows` full IIS. I can run other website which I am developing with IIS express and this LocalDB.

I also can see the content of all of my databases in Visual Studio`s Data tools which is connected to this LocalDB, with no problem.

I have tried: updating SQL Server 2019 LocalDB, delete and create the SQL Server LocalDB, reinstalling SQL Server 2019 LocalDB, but I still get that same error.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Latest version, is that Windows 11 or Windows 10 21H2

Comment: Windows 10 2004

Comment: This error code can also be triggered if you don’t have the correct redistributables installed on your computer.

Comment: But I uninstall and reinstall the LocalDB 2019 and also install the latest patches for SQL Server 2019. Also the database is working, except for this site which running with full IIS.

Comment: Which version of .NET does this site run?

Comment: This website runs with .NET 4.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this error with re-configuring the IIS for LocalDB. It was reset by a Windows Update.

I am using IIS for LocalDB approach 1:

```
Changing Application Pool Identity --> Windows Account
```